# Firewall software compatible for switch

Tags: firewall, bandwidth-control

We have "300 Series Managed Cissco Switche"

Now, I want something like http://www.sophos.com which can work with this switch as UI with firewall etc.

Could it be possible and if so how? Else can somebody tell me how in small business, I can control bandwidth of each pc as well as firewall to block some sites and apps(if posible)

Comment: If you want to go down the Sophos Route, they do a UTM Virtual appliance that is Free for SMB's (there are some restrictions) but very few.

Comment: I dont understand Virtual Device for SMB. I have router > Switch > All PC(Windows). SO how can this be fit in this scenario.

Comment: Then hire a consultant?

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean that you have a Linksys 300 Series Switch, made by Cisco. These are made for small businesses and have very few features (relative to what you're looking for). They do not have firewall capabilities, throttling, nor website blocking. They also can not run "software" (at least not like you're thinking).

You would control Internet access in a small business essentially the same way as any other business.

I would recommend using an old PC running software like [pfSense](http://pfsense.org) or another [Firewall Distro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_router_or_firewall_distributions). If you prefer a "hardware" solution, Cisco makes several devices, like the [WSA S170](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps10164/index.html) (Web Security Appliance). There are others as well, contact a reseller you trust and see what they recommend.

*In any case, you seem to be in way over your head and really need a consultant to set it up properly.*

<sub>Side note: We get a number of people here who try to manage people using technology; it doesn't work that way. This most commonly comes in the form of employees "screwing off" instead of working, and management thinks that by blocking certain websites the employees will go back to work. Studies have found that employees instead spend more time screwing off in other ways on average. The solution is to talk to the employees about not getting their work done, and if the problem continues to take further actions including replacing the employee.</sub>

Comment: Is there any hardware with these facilities availble for purchase. Which I can plug in network and if yes, can you suggest one?

Comment: I understand the Side note. But still, sometimes it would be needed for bandwidth control as well as site control for virus or other spam websites.